# Blade won't show data from PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have used a seeder to fill up data on my database! However, it doesn't show up on my blade file! and it just only the table. I tried various methods, including changing the route file and to add data directly from Phpmyadmin.

**Blade**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>bedrijven_id</td>
        <td>Body</td>
        <td>Created at</td>
        <td>Updated at</td>
        <td><button type="button">Soliciteer</button></td>
    </tr>
    @if(isset($data))
        @foreach($vacatures as $vacature)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$vacature['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$vacature['bedrijven_id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$vacature['body']}}</td>
                <td>{{$vacature['created_at']}}</td>
                <td>{{$vacature['updated_at']}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
class Vacatures extends Controller
{
    function viewLoad()
    {
        return view('vacatures');
    }

    function show() {
        $data = Vacature::all();
    
        return view('list', ['vacatures' => $data]);
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('list',\[Vacatures::class,'show'\]);
```

Comment: You have `@if(isset($data))` but according to your `blade` file code, the `$data` variable seems to be undefined on that `blade` file level and as you're calling `isset`, `PHP` will not throw an error but the `if` block will never be executed thus you don't see anything in your browser. Try to remove that condition.

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing MySQL databases. Your application is connecting directly to MySQL and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: i thik you need to update  @if(isset($data)) to be  @if(isset($vacatures ))

Answer (score 0):

The `$data` variable only exists within your controller, it is not passed through to the view.

Change this:

```
isset($data)
```

To this:

```
isset($vacatures)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of comments from @ths and @Omar, the `$data` is not passed to view.

By additional, `$vacatures` is instance of Eloquent collection at all.So for readable, you can check `$vacatures->isNotEmpty()` instead of `isset`

New laravel version also supports blade `@forelse` ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `isset($data)` use `isset($vacatures)`, because you passed `vacatures` to view file not `data`

```
@if(isset($vacatures))
    @foreach($vacatures as $vacature)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$vacature['id']}}</td>
            <td>{{$vacature['bedrijven_id']}}</td>
            <td>{{$vacature['body']}}</td>
            <td>{{$vacature['created_at']}}</td>
            <td>{{$vacature['updated_at']}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```